# Как избавиться от ошибки 'DatePicker' cannot be used as a JSX component в Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker, ant-design

После некоторых обновлений зависимостей, столкнулся с проблемой типизации компонентов, в частности DatePicker от Ant Design.

```
import { DatePicker, ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import locale from "antd/lib/locale/ru_RU";

<ConfigProvider locale={locale}>
    <DatePicker
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      onChange={handleChange}
      placeholder="Выберите дату"
      format="DD.MM.YYYY"
      status={status}
    />
</ConfigProvider>

"DatePicker" невозможно использовать как компонент JSX.
Тип экземпляра "Component<PickerProps<Moment> & { status?: "" | "error" | "warning" | undefined; }, unknown, any> & CommonPickerMethods" не является допустимым элементом JSX.
Типы, возвращаемые "render()", несовместимы между этими типами.
  Тип "React.ReactNode" не может быть назначен для типа "import("/home/user/Projects/my-frontend/node_modules/@types/react-redux/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode".
    Тип "{}" не может быть назначен для типа "ReactNode".ts(2786)
```

Что я пробовал?

1. Гуглил
2. Удалял node_modules
3. Удалял yarn.lock
4. yarn cache clean
5. Делал даунгрейд зависимостей
6. Открывал проект на другом устройстве
7. Менял версию TypeScript 4.6.3 <-> 4.7.0

Текущий package.json выглядит следующим образом:

[image: package.json]

Ошибка как висела, так и продолжает висеть. Прошу помощи сообщества. Возможно кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение проблемы - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71843120/8769345

Так как многие React библиотеки используют зависимость @types/react : "*", подгружаются типы для недавно вышедшей 18 версии, от туда и проблемы.

Временным решением было бы добавить resolution в package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.11"
}
```

Который был ограничивал версии этих пакетов для зависимостей их зависимостей.
Не забудьте удалить node_modules и *.lock файлы и заново загрузить все зависимости.

Гуд лак!